# Simple 1D Motion Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I am having a friendly debate with someone regarding the solution to a 1D motion test problem we both came across. It goes something like this (numbers changed to preserve integrity of test material).

A car drives for 50 miles at 50mph. It drives another 50 miles in the same direction, but this time at 100mph. What is the average velocity of the car?

I am convinced that it is 67mph. The other person argues that it is 75mph because they solved by taking a weighted average of the velocities based on the (equal) distance traveled. Can someone please help settle this debate for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Average velocity is the total distance traveled divided by the total time of travel. In other words, your journey will take the same amount of time if you travel at the average velocity all the way.

If your journey has $n$ legs, each traveled at constant velocity, the average velocity can be expressed as
$$ v_{avg} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nt_i} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n t_iv_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nt_i}. $$
So the average velocity is indeed a weighted average, but the weights are travel times, not distances.

Comment: Thanks! The other person brought up an interesting counter point: The problem does not explicitly specify that the two legs of the journey were done continuously. If some variable amount of time elapsed between the two legs, then using time as the weight would yield variable solutions, whereas using distance as the weight yields a single solution to the problem, which must be right. I got rather confused by this. Is the distance-based approach valid in this newly assumed case?

Comment: It is not valid. Average velocity has an established meaning in kinematics: total displacement divided by time interval. If you take a toilet break during your journey, your average velocity does indeed go down, depending on the duration of your break. For your purposes (depending on what you are planning to do with the average velocity you calculate), you may wish to exclude the duration of this break from the total time elapsed, and that's fine. But you can't use distances as weights and still call your average the "average velocity", even if it's a quantity that's useful to you.